# Is every Zariski dense set dense with regard to the standard topology?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I was wondering whether this is true or not, since it could turn in a powerful tool when working on the standard topology.

Comment: Somewhat related: A nonempty Zariski open subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$ is dense with regard to the standard topology, and in fact its complement has Lebesgue measure 0.

Comment: Maybe what you want is that every Zariski open set is open with respect to the standard topology? And moreover, in an irreducible variety, every Zariski open set is a dense open set in the standard topology.

Comment: @RobertFurber For example, I want to prove that a set $A$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard topology. If I manage to prove that $A$ is Zariski open, can I conclude $A$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard topology?

Comment: @WhiteCrow Yes, Zariski open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{C}^n$ (and more generally Zariski open subsets of any irreducible variety over these fields) are dense in the standard topology. As Robert Furber already stated in his comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. For example, every infinite subset of the affine line over $\mathbb{C}$ is Zariski dense, but there are plenty of infinite subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ which are not dense in the standard topology.

The converse, however, is true, since the Zariski topology is coarser than the standard topology.